# Fixed emitter current or does it change after connecting collector?

Tags: bjt

[image]

[image]

The first picture shows the base current while the collector is disconnected. It shows 8.3 mA. While the second on shows the base current reduces a bit (maybe because of Early effect) and the collector current is about 374 mA.

As far as I knew, whatever current is injected by the emitter into the base, the collector would take in the ratio of 1:beta. But when collector is disconnected, no one is there to take this 1:beta amount of current and so all the current injected by the emitter would come out from the base. The emitter current is fixed because the base circuitry is fixed. Now if we connect collector, emitter current should still be **fixed**(8.3 mA), but this time, the collector would take most of this 8.3 mA. But the total current is still be fixed (8.3 mA). But as seen in the picture it looks like the collector is drawing additional huge current from the emitter this is why now the collector current is 374 mA. What is wrong here?

Comment: No, only the base current is fixed. When you disconnect the collector then Ib = Ie. But if you reconnected the collector then the emitter current will be Ie = Ib/(beta +1).

Comment: @G36 so emitter current changes after adding collector?

Comment: Yes, Ie = Ib + Ic

Comment: Also, notice that the Vbe voltage should increase after you connect the collector. And the is why you see a "drop" in the base current.

Comment: @G36 the base current decreases because of early current, isn't it?

Comment: In my opinion, the base current decreases because the Vbe voltage increases after you reconnected the collector terminal.

Comment: @G36 But why would this Vbe increases after addition collector?its because  voltage drop around the base resistor decresses and that's because of the reduction in base current. Isn't it so?

Comment: In this case, Ie increases after adding the collector so, the Vbe voltage also needs to increase - the voltage drop across the base resistor decreases and this reduces the base current.

Comment: @Sayan I think you should first clean up your test by eliminating the Early Effect (set VA=1E9 for example) and the bulk resistances (set RB=1n, RC=1n, and RE=1n for example.) You are dealing with huge base currents as things are set right now (on the order of 10 mA.) If you do as I suggest, you should see the same voltage difference at the base node when using 500 ohms or 5000 ohms for your base resistance and regardless of the collector voltage. Once you demonstrate that fact to prove you've removed these residuals, addressing the rest will be more meaningful.

Comment: Having received such comprehensive answers to your question, I suggest you make it much more interesting with a small change - insert a few hundred ohm resistor into the emitter. Now the difference in the base currents in the two cases will be much more noticeable, which is of interest to explain...

Comment: The antique transistor is severely overloaded with the collector at 5V and it is so hot that it is smoking and is almost on fire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ebers-Moll

The very first *complete* (valid in all four quadrants of operation) model of the BJT was described by J. J. Ebers and J. L Moll (both associates at the IRE at the time) in 1954. Their Appendix uses Green's theorem and is essentially unrecognizable, today. This early BJT description has since gone through development into various versions: the *injection* model, then the *transport* model, and finally the *hybrid-*\$\pi\$ model -- through a series of refinements. (Just changes in perspective -- all three versions are computationally equivalent, if not conceptually so.)

All three versions are today lumped as the Level 1 model (having three versions.) In general, \$\text{EM}_1\$ is a DC model and its very good for figuring out the DC operating point of a BJT. Since that's the point here, we should apply it and see how things come out.

It's also non-linear. Which means it can be a bit of a mathematical pain, at times. And it makes a number of assumptions (such as the requirement for instantaneous maintenance of a quasi-equilibrium condition obeying the Boltzmann relation.) Which is why there are later developments that include two additional levels, \$\text{EM}_2\$ and \$\text{EM}_3\$, then Gummel-Poon and its variants, then VBIC, and then the continually revised MEXTRAM. You can quite literally make a life's work out of keeping up on the BJT, if you want.

Full non-linear versions aren't often taught, these days. Too many other subjects crowd the curriculum and it's relevance has been reduced to mainly its linearized form of the hybrid-\$\pi\$ version of \$\text{EM}_1\$ or \$\text{EM}_3\$, depending on whether or not the Early Effect is included. That need, the linearized small-signal model of the BJT, still continues to find its small place in the curriculum.

> The injection and transport models, despite early popularity into the
> mid 1970's, have mostly disappeared. They are useful if you want to
> re-connect back to the physics, though.

### Preface

To focus on the residuals and their explanation, you really need to eliminate some of the confounding factors. In your problem case, you used a very large base current for your simulation. And because of that, too many factors are conflated into your results. So it becomes far more confusing to try and tease out what you want to really know, when you do that.

(If you were an early experimental research physicist and you didn't already know the model and parameters, then you'd be stuck in this conflated, difficult-to-tease-out situation. And you'd have to come up with lots of different experiments to run.)

So the first thing I'd recommend here is to remove as many of the conflating factors as you can, especially those you don't need to understand because you already do, so that what's left helps you focus on answering your more fundamental question.

Since we all easily understand the idea of bulk resistance at each pin of the BJT as a series-resistor, let's get rid of these from the SPICE model so that these hidden values don't add further confusion.

This means setting **RC**, **RB**, and **RE** very close to zero. Since I don't trust SPICE programmers not to make things easier on themselves by forcing a zero value to some arbitrary non-zero value I don't know about, I will use very small but non-zero values here so that they aren't tempted. In this case, I'd suggest setting them to \$1\:\text{n}\Omega\$. No measurable effect, then!

Also, this means setting **VA** to some very large number, like \$1\times 10^9\:\text{V}\$. (To get rid of the Early Effect.)

So let's use this model:

```
.model MYNPN NPN(
        IS=1E-14 VAF=1E9 BF=200 BR=3 RB=1n RC=1n RE=1n IKF=0.3
        XTB=1.5 CJC=8E-12 CJE=25E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12 ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 )
```

That was "stolen" from LTspice's model of the 2N2222 and then modified according to my above recommendations and named **MYNPN**. If you are using LTspice in particular then you could also just write:

```
.model MYNPN ako:2N2222 NPN(VAF=1E9 RB=1n RC=1n RE=1n)
```

That just sucks up the existing model for the 2N2222 and modifies parameters, as shown above.

Removing the effects of **RC**, **RB**, **RE**, and **VA** will allow the SPICE simulation to better illustrate what you want to see and understand.

Also, since I'll use LTspice for the simulations, it's default temperature (\$27^\circ\text{C}\$, if memory serves) yields a thermal voltage of \$V_{_\text{T}}=25.865\:\text{mV}\$. I'll be using that value, where appropriate.

I'll use the \$\text{EM}_1\$ non-linear hybrid-\$\pi\$ model. This is ***not*** the model used in SPICE programs, however. Their results will be slightly different for this DC case because they take into account many factors learned later on. But hopefully, this will allow predictions that mirror the SPICE results.

This first step, the validation test, is needed before proceeding towards an understanding of the quantitative differences. If we can't match up well, then something serious is missing from our parameters under control and that means more work (or a better DC model.) If we match up well, then we can reasonably assume we've captured the important parameters under control and can then and only then hope to learn something (come to an experimental result) from the residuals between the two case examples and therefore explain ***why*** and by ***how much***.

So let's look at the model, itself.

### \$\text{EM}_1\$ Model

Here's the hybrid-\$\pi\$ non-linear model diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2BQQA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll use this diagram in the following sections.

The relevant equations for this model are:

1. \$\frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_{_\text{F}}} = \frac{I_{_\text{SAT}}}{\beta_{_\text{F}}} \cdot \left[ e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} - 1 \right] \$
2. \$\frac{I_{_\text{EC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}} = \frac{I_{_\text{SAT}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}} \cdot \left[ e^{\frac{V_{BC}}{V_T}} - 1 \right] \$
3. \$I_{_\text{CT}} = I_{_\text{CC}} - I_{_\text{EC}}, \rm{(generator \,\, current)}\$
4. \$ I_{_\text{C}} = \left( I_{_\text{CC}} - I_{_\text{EC}} \right) - \frac{I_{_\text{EC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}} \$
5. \$ I_{_\text{B}} = \frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_F} + \frac{I_{_\text{EC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}} \$
6. \$ I_{_\text{E}} = -\frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_F} - \left( I_{_\text{CC}} - I_{_\text{EC}} \right) \$

Note that all terminal currents point inward and must sum to zero. So for the NPN BJT, the emitter current will usually be negative.

### Disconnected Collector -- A Prediction

Your disconnected collector case looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDvsHv.png)</sup>

We know that \$I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}+I_{_\text{E}}=0\:\text{A}\$ (KCL) and as \$I_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{A}\$, from equation 5 and 6 we can write:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_F} + \frac{I_{_\text{EC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}}&=\frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_F} + \left( I_{_\text{CC}} - I_{_\text{EC}} \right)
\\\\ \therefore
\\\\
I_{_\text{CC}} &= \frac{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}{\beta_{_\text{R}}}\cdot I_{_\text{EC}}
\end{align*}$$

Also, from KCL and the fact that \$I_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{A}\$ we know that the generator current is the same as current in \$D_{_\text{EC}}\$. So starting with equation 3:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{CT}} &= I_{_\text{CC}}-I_{_\text{EC}}
\\\\
&=\frac{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}{\beta_{_\text{R}}}\cdot I_{_\text{EC}}-I_{_\text{EC}} &&= I_{_\text{CC}}-\frac{\beta_{_\text{R}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}\cdot I_{_\text{CC}}
\\\\
&=\frac{I_{_\text{EC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}}&&=\frac{I_{_\text{CC}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}
\end{align*}$$

From the above, we know the ratio of these two currents and therefore we know the ratio of the two diode currents:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{
   \frac{ I_{_\text{EC}} }{ \beta_{_\text{R}} }
  }{
   \frac{ I_{_\text{CC}} }{ \beta_{_\text{F}} }
  } &= \frac{ I_{_\text{EC}} }{ I_{_\text{CC}} } \cdot \frac{ \beta_{_\text{F}} }{ \beta_{_\text{R}} } = \frac{\beta_{_\text{F}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}
\end{align*}$$

Now, I just happen to know from the Shockley diode equation that there will be a voltage difference of:

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta V &= V_T\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\beta_{_\text{F}}}{\beta_{_\text{R}}+1}\right)
\\\\&=25.865\:\text{mV}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{200}{3+1}\right)
\\\\&\approx 101.2\:\text{mV}
\end{align*}$$

Since \$D_{_\text{EC}}\$ has the larger current, this will invert the polarity of the voltage across \$I_{_\text{CT}}\$ to the opposite you would expect, so this then subtracts from the base-emitter voltage you see outside the NPN BJT, causing the case with an open collector to appear to have a ***lower*** base-emitter voltage than the case where the collector is connected up.

***Note:*** I haven't yet bothered to calculate actual base voltages. You can do all that yourself using the Shockley diode equation. (Iteratively or else with a closed expression using the LambertW function.) All that I've done is make a prediction based upon the simplest complete NPN BJT model of what I would expect to see as a *difference* between base-emitter voltages in the two cases.

Let's see.

I've not run the test, yet. And I've ***never*** done this calculation before, as like many people I've not yet needed to look. So I'm frankly a little worried at this moment, hoping for the best but not knowing what LTspice shows me.

[image]

We find ...

... that LTspice shows \$846.916\:\text{mV}- 746.484:\text{mV}= 100.432\text{mV}\$!!!

Well, I'm no longer shaking in my boots. And the world is right, again.

Feel free to change \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ in the schematic, such that \$V_{_\text{CC}}\ge 1\:\text{V}\$ (or thereabouts -- the main idea is to make sure it is *above* the base voltage.) The results will be the same because **VA** (Early Effect) is nulled out in the above LTspice run. So the results should be identical.

If you are still curious, try changing **BR** from 3 to 4 (or 5, or whatever.) Then go back and try another run. See if the computed \$\Delta\,V\$ matches. (I have just tried a few times and it does match up every single time.) This is strong evidence that the experimental result (the conclusion reached from current theory and measurement from simulation) is correct. The generator current source voltage makes the difference.

### Summary

First, take note that this voltage difference ***cannot*** be explained by the slight differences in base current. Not even remotely.

I've also provided everything needed to do any and all of the computations you want. The **entire** four-quadrant model does a great deal for you. It is shockingly good, even given the fact that it still makes a fair number of assumptions.

Note that there is now just a single reason exposed into view to explain the voltage difference at the base. By eliminating the confusing factors that might have otherwise made this a much more difficult exploration, we can isolate the single element that leads to the difference. It tells you ***how*** and it tells you by ***how much***!

It's not just a bunch of hand-waving, after all.

I want to make something abundantly clear. There is a vast chasm of difference between hand-waving about possible "explanations" which *sound plausible* on the surface (*"Loki did it"*) for an observed effect on the one hand and then instead providing a theoretical explanation that is both quantitative and predictive, as well as providing an explanation, on the other hand. Keep this in mind. If an explanation doesn't provide quantitative prediction, it's not really an explanation. It's mere hand-waving if it cannot be used to make quantitative predictions (and associated, quantitative boundary conditions.)

P.S. I just decided to check to see what I get for the open collector voltage and it is ***also*** almost exactly \$8\:\text{mV}\$, which is what LTspice shows, above.

### Prediction Addendum

I proposed a result from the model above. But I wanted to subject it to further testing. I'm curious if something had escaped my view above and I wanted to subject it to yet another test. So I modified the schematic to change the **BR** parameter over a range and then compare it with the formula I developed based upon the Shockley diode equation.

[image]

Given that LTspice uses a more sophisticated model, I believe the results bear out the above, earlier conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

In this type of BJT configuration, the emitter current is going to be pretty close to the collector current, the difference being the value of the base current because, it doesn't magically flow into outer space, it also flows through the emitter. The truth is that emitter current minus the base current equals the collector current.

And this is pretty much what the meters in your simulation are telling you. When all points are connected (simulation 2)  the base current is slightly less than it is in scenario 1 due to an internal resistance inside the emitter called rE.

That internal resistance AND the total emitter current in effect, makes the forward diode junction of base and emitter have slightly more forward voltage and this slightly reduces the base current. Nothing to do with early effect.

Comment: are you talking about 25mv/Ie? The dynamic resistance?

Comment: I certainly am @sayan

Comment: @Andyaka One does need to account for the model values for model parameter RE (bulk emitter resistance) and possibly with model parameter RB (bulk base resistance.) The Early Effect would then also have an impact on RE. Once these are accounted for, there will be residual differences to account (no disagreement there.) But these other effects are unfortunately for this test *not insignificant* at the base and collector (when connected up) currents the OP is discussing.

Comment: @jonk you can do as deep as you wish and, the deeper you go with this or that limited model the closer you get and the more the relative errors stack up. I personally, on most linear BJT circuits I design, pretty much stop at rE then let a simulation do the best it can (better than any hand-calc model) and note, that you can't even rely on the sim getting some circuits right (in particular bias stages on class AB push pull amplifiers). So, go as deep as you feel is necessary but remember that you may still need to tweak values.

Comment: It really would @jonk be interesting to make a detailed hand calculation that progressively draws in other effects you mention to see what the impact is. I'd do it myself but am stuck in hospital with a tiny Android phone which has the worst predictive text known to man and, it's almost like I have to rewrite every damn sentence I type with my big clumsy fingers. I'm too old for using modern tech hehe.

Comment: @Andyaka Cripes. I ***hate*** using a cell phone for this site!!! Sorry about that. I'll consider the idea.

Comment: I mention it because I don't recall ever having seen a nice worked example specifically for a BJT and, if I dare say, you are one amongst us who demonstrated that skill.

Comment: @Andyaka Okay. I've added it. Hope it is interesting, if nothing else. ;)

Comment: @jonk as per your first comment above, I thought you were going to use that as the guideline for showing that modelling rE and ignoring early effect is prone to error.

Comment: @Andyaka Absolutely ***not***!! I only was pointing out that it would be a confounding factor that would keep someone from being able to *see* the real factor!! I knew this before writing. I was just pointing out that at the OP's current levels those would make it *even harder* to work out the real situation. I wanted to kind of bury the lead in that comment! (I was keeping the central idea to myself until I saw someone point it out. No one did.)

Comment: Unfortunately we are at cross purposes. I thought your initial comment was a subtle way of telling me my answer was wrong. Hence, I tried to pursue the truth not via arguing but by asking you to demonstrate that.

Comment: @Andy aka, you are referring to an "internal resistance inside the emitter called rE." (rE=25mV/Ie). May I remind you that such a resistance does not exist? It is just a pure artificial element used in one of the three equivalent small-signal BJT models. It models the transconductance gm=1/rE=d(Ie)/d(Vbe).

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to tell me. Are you saying that the effective voltage across base and emitter (that causes a certain base current to flow) does not change with a change in collector current?

Comment: No - let me explain: You wrote "That internal resistance AND the total emitter current in effect, makes the forward diode junction of base and emitter have slightly more forward voltage and this slightly reduces the base current." How can a non-existing "internal resistance" be responsible for a reduction of the base current? Can you explain this effect?

Comment: OK, maybe I should have said raises the "real internal emitter voltage that causes a negative feedback effect and a slight reduction in base current?

Comment: OK - I see. But I think, in this case and from the physical point of view, such a small feeedback effect is caused not by the "dynamic" resistance (25mV/Ie) but by the static path resistance Re of the emitter region within the transistor.  Yes, this is a possible explanation for the observed effect.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 peneth!

Your described circuits' effects have nothing to do with Early Effect.

Your two situations compare a disconnected collector (Ic=0mA) compared with a collector connected to a fixed voltage.

Early Effect is all about variation in Ic as Vcb is varied at a fixed Vbe or alternatively, variation in Vbe as Vcb is varied at a fixed Ic (or a combination of the two).

In your first picture, which has the collector disconnected, Ib is "programmed" by the base resistor (R1) and, because the collector is unconnected, no collector current can flow and so Ie=Ib.

In the second scenario, which has the collector connected, Vbe is forced to go to a voltage magnitude which must satisfy two relationships. Firstly the relationship between Vbe and Ic as determined by the Ebbers Moll equation and secondly the relationship between Ib and Ic as set by the transistor's β (where β = Ic/Ib). β varies with the collector current, temperature etc. As Vbe varies, the voltage across R1 varies which of course varies the base current.

In your two scenarios, when the collector is connected to +5V, Vbe must increase a little, reducing the voltage across R1 slightly which reduces the base current. This all happens in order to satisfy the relationship between Vbe and Ic (Ebbers Moll) and the relationship between Ic and Ib (β). This should keep the transistor and us happy!

But now, with the collector connected to +5V, the emitter current must equal the sum of the base and collector currents, Ie = Ic + Ib.

Comment: "Vbe must increase a little, .......which reduces the base current." Violation of Shockleys equation?

Comment: @LvW If Vbe increases then the voltage across the base resistor must reduce reducing the current through it thereby reducing the base current. If the current didn't reduce when Vbe increases then Ohms Law would be violated.

Comment: Yes - I know Ohms law.  But in your explanation Shockleys explanation would be violated.  I can read your statement "...when the collector is connected to +5V, Vbe must increase a little". This is just an assertion without explanation. Why do you think that "Vbe must increase"? I rather think, that the starting point of your "sequence of events" (Vbe increase) cannot be correct.

Comment: @LvW You're funny - Indulging in your usual modus operandi of trying to rubbish someone's else's answer instead of making the required significant corrections to your own. If you have any further doubts about the basic operation of a transistor circuit then wire one up on breadboard and take some measurements. I'm sure you will soon converge on the reality.

Comment: OK - you think I am funny . Why such a personal attitude? Why did you not simply answer the question "Why do you think that "Vbe must increase"? You have started with this assertion - so I think the answer to this question can solve the problem...

Comment: @LvW If I believed that you were for one minute motivated by an interest in the answer to your question then I would not hesitate to answer it. The problem is, and past experience of your on-line attitude has led me to believe this, your primary interest is to instigate a conflict  and win it. So, until you convince me otherwise, your best way forward is to implement the simple practical experiment which I have recommended.

Comment: I don't want to continue this "discussion" on this level with personal attacks. So you can continue to hesitate with the answer to a technical/factual question,

Comment: @LvW Good morning. I don't think I can interpret your last (maybe) comment as an attempt to "convince me otherwise" but if it is an attempt then it falls way short of the mark!

Answer (score 3):

Today I took the trouble to do some experiments with BG transistor 2T6551, Vcc = 12 V and two base resistors of 75 kohm and 10 kohm. I hope they will be useful to illustrate the answers here.

---

**1. RB = 75 kohm (low base current)** - [**my full movie**](https://photos.app.goo.gl/bd3FLXUW7LNrf46fA)

- **Disconnected collector, cold transistor**
  [image: RB 75k - disconnected collector, cold transistor]
- **Connected collector, cold transistor**
  [image: RB 75k - connected collector, cold transistor]

---

**2. RB = 10 kohm (high base current)** - [**my full movie**](https://photos.app.goo.gl/bWdbKL8ZcidJNR5XA)

- **Disconnected collector, cold transistor**
  [image: RB 10k - disconnected collector, cold transistor]
- **Connected collector, initially cold transistor**
  [image: RB 10k - connected collector, initially cold transistor]
- **Connected collector, heated transistor**
  [image: RB 10k - connected collector, heated transistor]
- **Disconnected collector, still heated transistor**
  [image: RB 10k - disconnected collector, still heated transistor]

Comment: Thank you - very interesting tests. Should be evaluated and verified.

Comment: I think, in particular the measurement (collector connected to 12V) with transition from "cold" to "hot" shows the influence of the temperature on base current and base-emitter voltage. I doubt if this effect is included in the SPICE simulations.

Comment: Exactly! As the transistor was heating up, VF gradually decreased... Ic increased... and eventually the power increased. And if I hadn't disconnected the collector from Vcc in time, the transistor would have "died"...

Answer (score 1):

Let me try a rather short answer:

I think, it is clear that in **both cases** (collector node open or not) the following equation applies:

**5V=Ib*R1 + Vbe.**

Using Shockleys equation for the B-E-junction: **Ib=Io*exp(Vbe/Vt -1)**
we can write (neglecting the "-1"):

**5V=Ib * R1 + Vt * ln(Ib/Io)**.

From this equation, I can derive that Ib will NOT decrease as a result of any (small) Vbe increase (as mentioned in some answers). More than that, this would sound somewhat contradictory (having Shockleys equation in mind).

On the other hand, the test has shown a small reduction in Ib - and the last equation shows that (for 5V constant) this is possible only for

**(1)**  a **small Vt increase**  together with

**(2)** a corresponding **increase of Io**.

Realizing that the resulting current Ic has a value of **375mA**, I think the expected temperature increase can be a rather realistic explanation for the observed effect (small Ib decrease).

**Note**: Assuming that the measured currents are sufficiently correct, a mathematical treatment must be based on the corresponding thermal resistance of the device.

**Comment**: Reading again the described experiment (Sayan´s question), I ask myself if the shown values are measured data or simulation results?
In the latter case, I am not sure if heating of the component is considered or not. (Are there simulation programs which include such heating effects?)

---

**Update/Addendum**

Yesterday I have simulated the circuit (using the 2N2923 model) - and I have exactly reproduced the values as shown in the original question. However, for finding the values for the 1st case (collector open) I had no other alternative than to use a very large resistor (Rc=1E12 ohms) because the simulator does not allow an open node.

Therefore, I suppose that the switch as shown in the original circuit (questioner Sayan) also provides a very large resistor in the "open" state.

**That means**: In this mode, the base-collector junction is forward biased (instead of being not activated due to an unconnected collector node). Hence, the BJT is in saturation. This can explain the base current increase if compared with case 2 (collector at +5V).

A simulation of the BJT (real model) with an open (unconnected) collector node seems to be not possible. Therefore, an answer to the original question can only be given on a theoretical and/or experimental basis (I think).

Comment: But jonk gives the correct answer. And you can have an "open collector" in LTspice. And real-world measurements confirm that the Vbe will change, just as simple EM model predicts

Comment: Really? LTSpice allows an unconnected node? I did not know that - PSpice and TOPSpice do not allow that. Thank you for the info.